# How do I actually set DefaultTabs in a Spotify app?

Tags: json, spotify

[The integration guidlines for the Spotify Apps API](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/guidelines/) mentions DefaultTabs and how it should be expressed in the `manifest.json` file to achieve tabbing in your Spotify app. Unfortunately I have problem getting this to work and the app that it refers to (Tabs, with the URI `spotify:app:tabs`) for example doesn't exist in my preview build of the Spotify application.

> The application can specify what tabs it wants in the manifest file, in the `DefaultTabs` attribute. The attribute must be a list of records. Each record must contain the attributes `arguments` and `title`. The title can, and should, be localized by making it into a record with attributes for each language (currently `en`, `fr` and `es`).

I have tried the following:

1. Adding this snippet to my `manifest.json` file:

   ```
   "DefaultTabs": [{
     arguments: [],
     title: {"en": "På TV4"}
   }
   ]
   ```
2. Quitting the Spotify application and reloading it.
3. Load my app by entering it's address `spotify:app:name` in the address field.

Here I expected to see the tabs loaded, but it wasn't. Any help with the correct syntax would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a few issues at first too, but the following snippet works for me:

```
"DefaultTabs": [
    {
        "arguments": "test",
        "title":  { "en": "test" }
    },
    {
        "arguments": "test2",
        "title": { "en": "test2" }
    }
]
```

I think you are probably missing the arguments.

Also check out the Kitchensink demo app and sourcecode in GitHub: https://github.com/ptrwtts/kitchensink